# Setting Java Enums values through dependency injection

Tags: java, enums

I created a class with a public nested enum class and some setters. The nested enum class uses variables with values from a properties file set through dependency injection to the outer class. I want the component that uses the outer class to be agnostic of the values of the enum and loop through each one individually. The enum will always be instantiated after the outer class so there's no worry about null values in the variables. I was told this isn't how enums are supposed to be used. The suggestion is to write a class that mimics the enum class instead of just using the enum. That seemed very dogmatic and I'm curious what people's thoughts are and possible alternatives. I had written something like:

```
public class myOuterClass {
    private static string1;
    private static string2;
    private static string3;

    public enum NestedEnum {
        MY_ENUM1("enum1: "+string1),
        MY_ENUM2("enum2: "+string2),
        MY_ENUM3("enum3: "+string3);

        private String enumValue = "";

        NestedEnum(String enumValue) {
            this.enumValue = enumValue;
        }

        public String getEnumValue() { return enumValue; }
    }


    public String printEnum(NestedEnum enum) {
        System.out.println(enum.getEnumValue());
        return enum.getEnumValue();
    }


    public void setString1(String string1) {
        this.string1 = string1;
    }
    public void setString2(String string2) {
        this.string2 = string2;
    }
    public void setString3(String string3) {
        this.string3 = string3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `static` is not an instance variable.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, instance variable cannot be declared `static`. So a getter/setter is pointless. I don't think IoC/Dependency Injection will work on static fields anyways. You need to use instance fields.

Comment: Thanks Polywhirl. Yes, this was part of the conversation as well and we where curious about it but they need to be class variables in order for the enum to be able to access them. Otherwise there's a "Non-static field cannot be referenced from a static context" error in the enum.  We use Spring for IoC/Dependency Injection and our property values do get injected and used by the enum.

Comment: Dynamic `enum`s? OMG... You must use a class for this!

Comment: Thanks Magnamag, can you give more detail or an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that your enums are not actually dependency-injected; rather, they own their own instantiation logic (as enums always do), and they simply rely, in a fragile and unenforceable way, on dependency-injection having completed before the enum class is loaded by the class-loader. (Note that, since the enum is public, you aren't really controlling when this will happen; and neither is your DI framework.)

One way to fix this is to have your enum's constructor call into your DI framework. (For example, if you're using Guice and have a singleton instance of your `Injector`, your enum's constructor can ask it for the appropriate instances, thereby guaranteeing the ordering.) This is not ideal -- it pollutes your class code with references to your DI setup -- but it's better than what you have.

Another approach, of course, is not to use `enum` to begin with: let your DI framework do its job and manage your instances for you. But it sounds like you've already rejected that approach; and who am I to argue?

---

**Edited to add:** another potential issue with your approach is that the only way to "reset" your enums is by stopping and restarting the JVM. If you have multiple versions of your properties-file (e.g., different language versions), then your test-framework probably will not be able to test that they all work properly. (My first suggestion above does *not* address this issue.)

Comment: Thanks ruakh, I'm not stuck to my solution and your last approach was suggested and is something I'll try.  I do want the user of the outer class to be agnostic of the values and just loop through them. An enum seemed like a good solution (until I saw issues with instantiation in unit  tests).  But the problem you state is an issue.  In my case what calls the enum and so will initially instantiate it is a cron job that runs daily, so the chance of hitting that race condition is small.  But yeah, it's there.

Comment: Re: "In my case what calls the enum and so will initially instantiate it is a cron job that runs daily, so the chance of hitting that race condition is small": I wasn't so much referring to race conditions -- though you're right that there is one -- as to the fact that your `enum` is `public`, so you're not actually *enforcing* the requirement that it never gets loaded until that cron-job runs. Generally if you care about when a class is loaded, it should be `private`; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom for a good example.)

Comment: Thanks ruakh, very helpful.  I've begun to use a different data structure to handle this.

Comment: @ruakh Could you please tell me more about this "One way to fix this", I'm digging for days :)

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim: I think I said all that can be said *generally* about that approach. Anything else would depend on the rest of your code.